# Need to find a transistor

Tags: transistors

Repairing the Audio Oscillator section in my B&K Mod. 970 Radio Analyst, which has a bad 16L64 NPN transistor. I'm not able to find a replacement.
Any help is more than appreciated.

Note:
Revised and corrected. The Transistor number is 16L64 NOT 16L46 and it is a NPN NOT a PNP.
I'd like to apologize to every one for my mistake.
I found the schematic and will using the instrument for repair.

Comment: All i'm getting in search for that are light bulbs. Are you sure that is what it says on the transistor?

Comment: Do you have a schematic?  Picture of the transistor?  If you're trying to get running again, as opposed to historically-correct restoration, we can probably find a modern replacement.

Comment: I don't recognize 16L46, and I'll assume you did your homework searching for it.  It is either a old designation or a internal part number.  The best bet is to find or infer the parameters and replace with a modern part.  If it's in a TO-92 case or similar, try a 2N4403 and see if it works.

Comment: A picture is needed as the case style can help us look for the replacement. Digging through my ECG 1996 cross reference book, we have 16L42, 43, 44, 62, 63, and 64. No 46. However, they are all cross referenced to the same replacement and it's an *NPN* transistor. Are you sure it's a PNP? Since it's bad you can't use the typical multi-tester method of determining the type. The schematic is needed instead, detailing which pin connects to which (importantly ground). Please provide those and I can give you the specs and modern replacement parts.

Comment: I apologize deeply for posting incorrect information. I found the schematic and made the corrections to my post. You are correct...I feel like a fool. I do use the instrument, since I have several transistor radio that needs repair. I'd be more than happy to post that portion of the schematic if I knew how. Thanks again,

Comment: @RayPalmore - If you found the schematic, please post it!  That may allow us to make better estimations of the required parameters for the part.

Comment: @shimofuri - I removed the tags "part-search" and "part-replacement" you created. Think twice before creating new tags. Before you know we'll end up with "part-allocation", "part-soldering", "part-testing" and what more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NTE](http://www.nteinc.com/index.php)'s cross reference, 16L64 can be replaced by NTE107 which is described as a "Silicon NPN Transistor - UHF Oscillator for Tuner" and comes in a TO-92 package.  As the exact copyright status of NTE literature is unknown to me and to avoid any copyright issue, I will not be posting the specifications here.  Instead, here is the link to the [datasheet](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/100to199/pdf/nte107.pdf).

If you are in the US, you can check for availability of the NTE part using the "Check Stock" [button](http://nte01.nteinc.com/nte%5CNTExRefSemiProd.nsf/%24all/FAF2288C5D27F2E885257910007DC12D?OpenDocument).  I highly recommend buying from NTE to support their business.  They had been providing good cross reference service for decades (formerly known as ECG by Philips).

Other common transistors for replacement are [2N3855A](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/DatasheetsImg/Datasheets-X1/tnDSA886000-93.jpg) and [BC549](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/BC/BC549.html). A preferable replacement from Fairchild is [KSC388](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/KS/KSC388.html).

Comment: WARNING: Before installing the replacement, make sure that the pins are in proper orientation. Please check the datasheet and review the schematics.

Comment: This will surely solve my problem.