# How to find a replacement for an antiquated transistor 2N2148

Tags: transistors, repair, components

I need to replace a transistor in my guitar amplifier.  The model number listed on the original schematic is 2N2148.  It is in a TO3 package and the rest of the specs are listed [here](http://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=1648).

I am having trouble trying to find a suitable modern replacement and I am unsure whether I should buy a NOS given that it is a germanium component.  I found a few on Ebay [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-RCA-2n2148-PNP-Germanium-60-Volt-Power-Transistor-Mica-Heat-Washer-/251166892104?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a7ab6a048) and [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2N2148-Welco-Transistor-SES-/350548726740?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item519e5513d4)
but I could really use some advice as to what to do in this situation.

Comment: I hope people should explain why they are down-voting questions.

Comment: You should read the FAQ and you will know the reason of vote down. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: Sorry, I did not know the FAQ.  I am mainly on other Stack Exchange sites and I could not find any other one that would fit this question better.  Do you think that I should use a NOS component or a modern replacement due to the fact that it is germanium and prone to degrade?

Comment: The intention of the OP is about repairing a circuit. Research effort is shown and the question is both practical and answerable. It is my opinion that this question is beyond a simple "buying or shopping recommendation" one. We have the "repair" tag available to support the question and a precedent here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30459/need-to-find-a-transistor/ Perhaps the moderators would like to deliberate on this in meta?

Comment: @Chetan: I have read the FAQ and still don't see a reason for the downvote.

Comment: The text of the question is okay quality.  But the title is low quality and leaves an impression if helplessness.  " *How to find a replacement for an antiquated transistor 2N2148?* "  might be a better title, IMO.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have not downvoted but suggested a probable reason why it could have been down-voted.

Comment: I don't see this as "not a real question" on the repair front because the question is reasonably scoped and answerable. I don't think it is off-topic as shopping advice because it is closer to "how do I choose" vs. "pick something for me".

Comment: You need to check the circuit around it: sometimes transistors are used in pairs, like when using a "long-tailed pair" as differential amplifier.  In that case, you need to exchange the whole pair for sensible results, using two transistors of same origin (BJT transistors tend to be reasonably similar in one batch, something that isn't similarly the case with FETs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of looking for a similar part is called "cross referencing."  That is usually done to look for replacements or to approximate the specifications of the original part.

One of the established electronic cross reference database is the former ECG line of Philips.  That business was bought out by NTE Electronics and you can access their service [here](http://www.nteinc.com/index.php).

Searching for 2N2148 in NTE, the suggested replacement is [NTE121](http://nte01.nteinc.com/nte%5CNTExRefSemiProd.nsf/%24all/65A617C75915D56785257910007E4E8E?OpenDocument). Use the "Check Stock" button to search for where you can buy the replacement.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help!  Do you think that I should buy a new product rather than a NOS then?

Comment: This is more of an opinion (and "buying recommendations" are technically off-topic in this site): I would rather buy from an established business that had specialized in parts replacement than from Ebay. For one, NTE parts carries a warranty both in their suitability as replacement and quality. The ECG line, if I recall correctly, has been there since the 70s.

Comment: Sorry again.  I am asking for the purpose of the electrical circuit, not for the best price, etc.  I know that germanium transistors are more prone to fail as time goes on compared to silicon.  I just was not sure if a NOS part made in the 70's would be a safe bet or if a newer part was necessary/recommended.  Thank you for your advice and I understand that I am skirting the edge of acceptability in terms of "buying recommendations" but I am still new to electrical circuits and just trying to make the best decision.  Thank you for all your help

Comment: Given your concerns, buy more than one...

Answer (score 1):

There are many replacements for the 2N2148 germaniun PNP transistor:

You can use any of the following transistors listed in *{dead link}* for the original part to replace it:
2N3617
2N3618
AL102
AL103
AUY22